# Generating integers properly on click

Tags: java, android

I am having trouble with my code regarding integers I generate when a  function is called - my code is meant to be a mathematical game where user answers random arithmetic questions with numbers from 1 to 12 and that I can do but the code seems to be generating new random values before allowing the user to answer to a previous question, meaning the user answers to the next question that is not shown on screen. I think it's described better inside the code where I commented on specific lines.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {




Random r = new Random();
int points1 = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int value1 = r.nextInt(12 - 1) + 1;             //1st randomized set of values
    int value2 = r.nextInt(12 - 1) + 1;             // ^
    TextView Number1 = findViewById(R.id.number1);
    Number1.setText(""+value1);                            //assigns randomized values to TextViews
    TextView Number2 = findViewById(R.id.number2);
    Number2.setText(""+value2);                            // ^^

}

public void onSubmitCheck (View view) {
    reset();                                               //When button Submit is clicked

}       //^ ^ Issue starts here when we click "submit" - the code generates new random values before checking the old ones against the mathematical expression in line 50..
        //..meaning the user is already answering to the SECOND question before even attempting the first one.

public void reset(){
    int value1 = r.nextInt(12 - 1) + 1;            //Assigns 2nd randomized values
    int value2 = r.nextInt(12 - 1) + 1;            // ^
        TextView Number1 = findViewById(R.id.number1);
        Number1.setText("" + value1);
        TextView Number2 = findViewById(R.id.number2);
        Number2.setText("" + value2);
    TextView Answer = findViewById(R.id.Answer);
    TextView displayPoints = findViewById(R.id.points);
    EditText Attempt = findViewById(R.id.Attempt);
    int userAnswer = Integer.parseInt(Attempt.getText().toString());    //compares inputted value to an answer from line 50
    if (userAnswer == value1 + value2) {                                    //LINE 50
        Answer.setText("Correct!");
        point();
        displayPoints.setText(""+ points1);

    } else {
        Answer.setText("Wrong :( Answer was: " + (value1 + value2));
    }
```

So finally, what I am trying to achieve is generated values on creation (onCreate) that user can answer, then after the users input and submition the app should generate new values and allow the user to answer again. I am not expecting a full work done for me but ideas that could lead me towards an answer as I really would like to learn and understand my problem.

I tried different things but I guess it's just my experience and knowledge that is blocking me from finding a solution - I am a begginer and self-taught.

**EDIT FOR RANDOM OPERATOR ISSUE;**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Random r = new Random();


int points1 = 0;
int value1, value2;
TextView Number1;
TextView Number2;
TextView Answer;
TextView displayPoints;
EditText Attempt;
TextView Operator;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Number1 = findViewById(R.id.number1);
    Number2 = findViewById(R.id.number2);
    Answer = findViewById(R.id.Answer);
    Operator = findViewById(R.id.operator);
    displayPoints = findViewById(R.id.points);
    Attempt = findViewById(R.id.Attempt);

    value1 = r.nextInt(12 - 1) + 1;             
    value2 = r.nextInt(12 - 1) + 1;             
    Number1.setText("" + value1);                            
    Number2.setText("" + value2);

    int operator = r.nextInt(4 - 1) + 1;        //HERE
    switch (operator)
    {
        case 1: operator = '+';
            break;
        case 2: operator = '-';
            break;
        case 3: operator = '*';
            break;
        case 4: operator = '/';
            break;
    }
    Operator.setText("" + operator);
}




public void onSubmitCheck(View view) {
    reset();

}

public void reset() {


    int operator = r.nextInt(4 - 1) + 1;                   //here
    switch (operator)
    {
        case 1: operator = '+';
            break;
        case 2: operator = '-';
            break;
        case 3: operator = '*';
            break;
        case 4: operator = '/';
            break;
    }

    int userAnswer = Integer.parseInt(Attempt.getText().toString());
    if (userAnswer == value1 + operator + value2) {
        Answer.setText("Correct!");
        point();
        displayPoints.setText("" + points1);

    } else {
        Answer.setText("The answer was: " + (value1 + value2));
    }

    value1 = r.nextInt(12 - 1) + 1;             
    value2 = r.nextInt(12 - 1) + 1;            
    Number1.setText("" + value1);
    Number2.setText("" + value2);
    Operator.setText("" + Operator);

}
public void point() {
    points1 = points1 + 1;

}


public void onSubmitNext(View view) {
    reset();
}
```

}

Comment: Try to put everything after the 6th row of the `reset()` method into an own method (e.g. `validateAttempt()`) and call this method before the `reset()` method in the `onSubmitCheck(...)` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make value1 and value2 global and reset the values only after comparing it with old values. Made some other re-arrangements too.

This could be your code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


Random r = new Random();
int points1 = 0;
int value1, value2;
TextView Number1;
TextView Number2;
TextView Answer;
TextView displayPoints;
EditText Attempt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Number1 = findViewById(R.id.number1);
    Number2 = findViewById(R.id.number2);
    Answer = findViewById(R.id.Answer);
    displayPoints = findViewById(R.id.points);
    Attempt = findViewById(R.id.Attempt);

    value1 = r.nextInt(12 - 1) + 1;             //1st randomized set of values
    value2 = r.nextInt(12 - 1) + 1;             // ^
    Number1.setText("" + value1);                            //assigns randomized values to textEdits
    Number2.setText("" + value2);                            // ^^

}

public void onSubmitCheck(View view) {
    reset();                                               //When button Submit is clicked

}       //^ ^ Issue starts here when we click "submit" - the code generates new random values before checking the old ones against the mathematical expression in line 50..
//..meaning the user is already answering to the SECOND question before even attempting the first one.

public void reset() {

    int userAnswer = Integer.parseInt(Attempt.getText().toString());    //compares inputted value to an answer from line 50
    if (userAnswer == value1 + value2) {                                    //LINE 50
        Answer.setText("Correct!");
        point();
        displayPoints.setText("" + points1);

    } else {
        Answer.setText("Wrong :( Answer was: " + (value1 + value2));
    }

    value1 = r.nextInt(12 - 1) + 1;            //Assigns 2nd randomized values
    value2 = r.nextInt(12 - 1) + 1;            // ^
    Number1.setText("" + value1);
    Number2.setText("" + value2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am now trying to add a random operator to the math expression any ideas/documentations I could read? I had a look online but most of it is too advanced for me to understand.

Comment: are you currently showing the '+' indicator in the UI?

Comment: Ah, yes I am, I'm gonna show " " and rename the id to "operator".

Comment: you could make a string array of different operators and generate a random integer(within size of the array) for picking an operator from the array and then do the operation with that operator.

Comment: I used a switch statement as this seemed simple, could you have a look at my edited version of the post? It does not fully work - on start it displays a number 4 as a operator and then letter "a" when user answers the question.

Comment: this is wrong. dont assign string to operator since you have declared it as int

Comment: use another string variable and then assign each operator to it in cases. then you can use that string to set the text field. When evaluating the answer you should again have a switch case to perform different operations correspindingly

Answer (score 0):

```
static int points1 = 0; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView Number1 = findViewById(R.id.number1);
    TextView Number2 = findViewById(R.id.number2);
    TextView Answer = findViewById(R.id.Answer);
    EditText Attempt = findViewById(R.id.Attempt);
    TextView displayPoints = findViewById(R.id.points);

    generateNumbers();

}

public void onSubmitCheck (View view) {
    checkResult();
    Attempt.clear();                                              
} 

private void generateNumbers () {
    Random r = new Random();
    value1 = r.nextInt(12 - 1) + 1;
    value2 = r.nextInt(12 - 1) + 1;

    Number1.setText(""+value1);                   
    Number2.setText(""+value2);

}

void checkResult() {
    int userAnswer = Integer.parseInt(Attempt.getText().toString());   
    if (userAnswer == value1 + value2) {                 
        Answer.setText("Correct!");

        points1++;

        displayPoints.setText(""+ points1);

    } else {
        Answer.setText("Wrong :( Answer was: " + (value1 + value2));
    }
}
```

---

Try this, from the beginning point this code will work. It will be a better option if you use another button called **Next** for next Value generation . It may help you to understand the code.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that solution with another button. Your code gives me back a few errors - some values are not resolvable.